# Excel Automation From .NET - creating a new worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I am attempting what seems like a simple task: using C# to create a new Excel document containing new worksheets.

For some reason, I am getting a strange COM error (0x800A03EC)

Has anyone managed to get this to work? Does anyone have suggestions as to how to troubleshoot this?

I've isolated this into the minimum amount of code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ExcelAutomation
{
    public static class ExcelTests
    {
        public static void CreateWorksheet()
        {
            try
            {
                var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                app.Visible = true;
                var workBooks = app.Workbooks;
                var newWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
                Worksheet existingWorksheet = (Worksheet)newWorkbook.Sheets[1];

                Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet)newWorkbook.Sheets.Add
                        (
                            null, // before
                            existingWorksheet,
                            null, // 1,
                            null //XlSheetType.xlWorksheet
                        );
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Caught COMException. Message: \"{0}\"", ex.Message));  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output window now says:

Caught COMException. Message: "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I'm making is to use *null* for optional values that I don't want to set.

Instead I should use [System.Reflection.Missing.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.missing.value.aspx)

```
        Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet)newWorkbook.Sheets.Add
                (
                    existingWorksheet, // before
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, // 1,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value //XlSheetType.xlWorksheet
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this will help you

Visit http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Adding+New+Worksheets+to+Workbook+and+Activating+a+Sheet

Comment: Simply posting a link to a large page of text does not count as an answer.